# How to solve ode equation which is written in matrix form by ode45 MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode

I want to solve ode equation which is written in matrix form. `A=[-0.0178 0 -10;0 -0.2352 10;1 -1 0];` and `B=[0.3313 -8.9335;0 3.7245;0 0]`. Variables are `x=[x1;x2;x3];`. Input are `u=[v;f];`. `xdot=[x1dot;x2dot;x3dot];`. Finally the ode becomes - xdot=A*x + B*u, initial conditions are `x0=[0;0;0];`. Inputs are  v=0.05 and f=0;

How to solve this equation through anonymus function by ode45. Another question is that if there is larger matrix say 100 order, then it is very difficult to write separate form then how can I solve if they are in particular form like xdot=A*x +B*u where xdot is n * 1, A is n * n, x is n * 1, B is n * m and u is m * 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default solvers assume that the ode is time dependent (which they normally aren't). Also, I like to start off very general so I would create a function in a separate file (maybe mySystem.m) with five variables: t, x, u, A and B. It would look something like

```
function dx = mySystem(t, x, u, A, B)
dx = ... (Insert system equations)
end
```

then in the script where you define A, B, and u and where you ultimately want to use something like ode45 I would create an anonymous instance of this function which has the inputs that ode45 wants, ie t and x. It would look something like:

```
A = ...;
B = ...;
u = ...;
f = @(t, x) mySystem(t, x, u, A, B);
```

now, this f can easily be used ode45:

```
tspan = [t0, tf];
x0 = ...;
[t, y] = ode45(@f, tspan, x0);
```

If you now need to change B or A or u you just do it in your script, and you can reuse mySystem for other problems.

I do realize mySystem is a one-liner and could be an anonymous function too, but other ode's may not fit on one line and will need a separate file. This way the programming becomes more consistent. It is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ville. Further more that I want the output of the system where output equation matrix is  ```Youtput= C * x + D * u```. Here ```C=[0 1.42 0];``` and ```D=[0 -15];```. _x_ and _u_ are same as state and input variable. How can I code it, since we used anonymous function so we couldn't get _x_ value to multiply herewith.

Comment: The outputs [t y] from ode are the x-solutions at the points in t. You can use the broadcasting in MATLAB and just compute Youtput = C•y + D•u to get a vector containing Youtput at all the times t. You can then for example plot it with plot(t, Youtput)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ville. Your solution is very useful for me in solving ode equation. I am facing another problem related with input. I have three inputs and last two inputs are delayed in nature. For example- First input act at t=0; second input act after 20 seconds before that it is zero and final one act after 40 seconds before that it is zero. Whenever I applied it in Function script using for loop the main strict create a problem that 'unrecognized variable u' and when I write it in main function it crates problem what is t? How to execute this code?

Comment: If I understand you correctly consider letting u be a function of time, say for example u = @(t) 1*(t == 0 || t == 20 || t == 40). Then set f = @(t, x) mySystem(t, x, u(t), A, B).